# Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently updated the Android Studio to it's latest version, and now I am experiencing a headache with an exception in Gradle build.

Every time I run the project, two or three times before it succeed, I get the following error:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ': ProjectName:
mergeDebugResources'.
Java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

After trying again a couple times, the error does not happen again until the next run.

Does anybody have any idea of why this is happening? The project worked just fine 'til the update, never got any error before...

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

There is an issue reported about gradle build problems, it is not the same, but the solution seems to solve the mergeResourceDebug issues too. (issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56158). In the comments it is stated that the solution is solved in Gradle 0.4.3.

To use Gradle 0.4.3, the build.gradle file needs to be updated manually.  (Updating Android Studio does not change the build file)

Here is what I changed In build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'
}
```

Since changing this, I have not seen any more mergeDebugResource issues when running my project.  Hope this helps!

Edit: to stay up to date with Gradle you can change the version number to 0.4.+

Comment: In my case it when doing so, it says : A problem occured while evaluating project. > Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8.

Comment: I already have such a line in my build.gradle (the one in the project root), but the problem persists. And this is a brand new project in a fresh install.

Answer (score 52):

It happens to me only when modifying the XML files on the project. If you rebuild the entire project before running (Build > Rebuild Project) it doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: I hope they fix that soon, on a big project, rebuild everything is a pain :/

Comment: Delete build folder and rebuild :-)

Comment: @Dusty saved my day!

Answer (score 32):

inside your project directory, run:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

or from Android Studio select:

```
Build > Clean Project
```

Updated: As @VinceFior pointed out in a comment below

Comment: I accessed this in Android Studio by selecting Build > Clean Project.

Answer (score 19):

You may have a corrupted .9.png in your drawables directory

Comment: My issue was fixed after reading your comment. I think exception is common for multiple issues.

Comment: i found same issues, i removed corrupted png file and file > invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Even adding to app's gradle: `android { aaptOptions {     cruncherEnabled = false}...` does not fix the problem since png files might be really corrupted: `AAPT err(Facade for 676904551): ERROR: 9-patch image \\?\C:\YouApp\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\yourimage.9.png malformed.
AAPT err(Facade for 676904551):        Frame pixels must be either solid or transparent (not intermediate alphas).
AAPT err(Facade for 676904551):        Found at pixel #395 along bottom edge.`. I regenerated png files at Tinypng.com and now it is building.

Answer (score 16):

This error could also happen if the generated build file path exceeds the windows max path length of 255 characters. Make sure your project path is not too long, use short names as well.

Comment: you rock rajesh...this is root cause of this problem

Comment: I tried to recreate the project in main directory (D:), but to no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This would also happen if there is/are any additional folder/files in resource folder which are not supported by Android.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve, it simply downgrade your gradle version like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:YOUR_GRADLE_VERSION'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:OLDER_GRADLE_VERSION_THAT_YOUR'
}
```

for example:

**YOUR_GRADLE_VERSION**  =  3.0.0

**OLDER_GRADLE_VERSION_THAT_YOUR**  =  2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of above works, I have just **renamed** the project name, everything works well.

**Example:**

My project name **Before** -  **sticky-headers-recyclerview-master**

My project name **After** -  **SHRV**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: in that case, you have simply followed [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18681672/1668057)

Answer (score 0):

My problem solve this one

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

to

```
provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: "Solve this to this"? What does that mean? Change it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I changed **package name** this issue appeared, I just followed below steps to fix my problem:

1. **Removed previously installed apk (uninstall)**
2. **Applied project clean**
3. **Run the app**

Answer (score 0):

Had to change build tools version from some old one in `build.gradle` for project **module**:

```
android {
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Gradle task called "cleanBuildCache" just run this task clean the cache then re-build the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed the space from project folder name
From:
MyApp latest

To:
MyApp_latest

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to the latest gradle build tool version and it works.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a faulty name of a drawable file.  I had an image I was using that was named `Untitled`.  Changing the name solved my problem.