# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > -1

Tags: android, xml, resources

I'm new in android and i have this error, i've been trying looking everywhere for the solution and still don't know how to solve this. I have this :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> -1

and the effect is every R in my activities got "cannot resolve symbol R"

i've been trying to clean, build and sync with gradle but still not working..

this is my resources:
strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">mLibrary AeU</string>
    <string name="action_search">action_search</string>
    <string name="search_hint">search_hint</string>
    <string name="welcome">welcome</string>
    <string name="btn_logout">btn_logout</string>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#2f2d79</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <color name="callNumber">#666666</color>
    <color name="author_and_year">#888888</color>
    <color name="list_divider">#d9d9d9</color>
    <color name="list_row_start_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="list_row_end_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="list_row_hover_start_color">#ebeef0</color>
    <color name="list_row_hover_end_color">#ebeef0</color>
</resources>
```

dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="title">17dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="author">15dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="callNumber">13dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="year">13dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I need your help.

Comment: `cannot resolve symbol R` usually means you have an error in one of your resource files. i.e layout or style etc

Comment: Try to clean your project and run again.

Comment: Can you provide the logs related to this from your "gradle console" tab?

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/22583418/6197251

Answer (score 0):

You should check your resource files and `AndroidManifest` file. It may be releated by image resources (They should be .png file and their names must be in lower case.). It must be a slight mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!! thankyou guys for commend. the problem is in my assets folder is still have a library fil that