# Android studio error: app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this problem
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

I saw that people tell that it's because image format but I just installed android studio I didn't upload any picture to it, or wrote any code, it is in his starting code:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583418/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-android-studio answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: “Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'” if project is created on drive C:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-projec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 2 probability that makes the error:

1. Maximum 260 characters for the file path. Here the excerpt from the [Windows Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath):

> Maximum Path Length Limitation
>
> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The  characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

2. Your username is using some special unicode instead of ascii, something like **`userñame`**

Answer (score 1):

The second one was the answer, it doesn't accept space so it told me to change my user name (which obviously was a trouble), so in the path to save the application I use, instead of a space in my username a low-bar "Doctor_mcmuffing".