# Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. and Failed to build some directory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

At first install running a program all is normal. And then it's happened since I add a splash screen in there. I've reinstalled the application but nothing was changed. First run normal and the second run is failed again. I try to check my gradle and the file, but no one problem that found in there.

How I can fix this problem?

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Failed to transform aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.2-6503028) to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for Aapt2Extractor: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\aapt2\4.1.2-6503028\6d9042942daa27a40e3ff66254cb2a82a7f0b69f\aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows.jar.
> > Failed to create directory 'C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0acdb043263d98cb86ad08d6f4b1bd1a\aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task :':app:mergeDebugResources'. Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583418/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot isolate the issue but you can try these things if the caches got scrambled or something

1. try clean build or invalidate caches/restart
2. If the above didn't work delete the build/caches folder and rerun. From what I can see you can go here C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches and delete the caches folder, this will most certainly resolve your issue.
3. If that also didn't work the ultimate resort would be nuking the caches

- Close Android Studio
- open terminal and go to project location (cd project location)
- ./gradlew clean
- ./gradlew --stop
- rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
- ./gradlew assembleDebug
- Open Android Studio and gradle sync

I hope it works.

Comment: Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\ASUS\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0acdb043263d98cb86ad08d6f4b1bd1a'
  Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
  - C:\Users\ASUS\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0acdb043263d98cb86ad08d6f4b1bd1a\aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows

Comment: It didn't works and the output is like that :(

Comment: @CindyMagnolia Would you try to turn everything off? I think it happens cause of the program is running in the background.