# Solved Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. while First Install Android Studio and Run Project

Tags: android-studio

install Android Studio Newly and Create one Project.
after Re-Build Gradle Give Bellow Error

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Android Version 4.1.3
Gradle version 6.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task :':app:mergeDebugResources'. Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583418/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-android-studio)