# Gradle execution error in Android Studio (Ubuntu)

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, android-studio

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu and Android Studio. I have installed open jdk7 (for some reason it ended up in directories suffixed "amd64" even though I am running an Intel CPU, but I guess that's just a name?) as well as some SDK files.

I then created an empty project and now I am getting an error displayed near the bottom of the window. I guess this is a Gradle error (am very new to AS)

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HockeyGame/app/build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: Error: Cannot run program "/opt/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I was thinking maybe this was a file privilege problem (because aapt does indeed seem to exist), so I set the privileges to 775 recursively. And I am also starting AS with sudo (sudo sh studio.sh).

Any ideas? I am partly trying AS out in Android because I was having problems getting it to run under a cluttered Windows install (and also for the fun of it), so this is disappointing.

edit: It turned out 64-bit Ubuntu isn't fit to run 32-bit executables out of the box.

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, but you shouldn't be running Android Studio using `sudo` - you should be running it using your own user. You should also definitely not be setting 755 privileges - only directories and executables should have the executable bit set. If you want to make sure, try `chmod -R ugo+rX` (with a capital `X`) - but this shouldn't be a problem if you just open the Android Studio bundle. Personally, I made it work with the Oracle JDK, I don't know what the deal is with the amd64 suffix

Comment: [Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17121033/1693859)

Comment: @SamRad okay I'm having a look there. So I added the classpath bit to build.gradle, but got a build script error saying "unsupported Gradle DSL method found". Anything else in there I could try? Maybe that thread has become a bit dated?

Comment: @orip thanks, I will refrain from starting with sudo, and also reconsider the privilege settings. And perhaps install oracle JDK instead of open. Do you think that this realistically could solve my problem?

Comment: Not sure about the original problem with aapt not being recognized, but at this point it's a problem with your build.gradle file. I'm guessing you've put stuff in your top-level build file that belongs in the module-level build file instead.

Comment: @ScottBarta I haven't touched my build files. This literally happened as soon as I had created the project file.

Comment: Well, I reinstalled the OS and then got me some Oracle JDK going. To no avail. Same problem. Right out of the box.

Comment: aapt is built for 32 bit only. Is your OS configured to run 32bit executables?

Comment: Yes, I learned this via Reddit the other day. I do feel a bit silly. But at the same time, I didn't see it mentioned in the install guides I read.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it by running

sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67155

Comment: Saved me from massive pain