# android studio mergedebugresources java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently updated the Android Studio to it's latest version, and now I am experiencing a headache with an exception in Gradle build.

Every time I run the project, two or three times before it succeed, I get the following error:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ': ProjectName:
mergeDebugResources'.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(no error message)
```

For your quick reference I am using Android Studio 1.5 (latest version)

Please help me were I am going wrong. Please give at least any trick, idea, or hint to resolve this issue.... Your time and efforts in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure this is the solution can u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception

Comment: Which gradle plugin version are you using? It's defined in the main build.gradle file pf your project. Something like this: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: Yes its classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your build folder and rebuild project.