# Unable to solve error in android: mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-build

Hi I am getting this error while importing an eclipse project.

```
  Information:Gradle tasks [:qpals:generateDebugSources, :qpals:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :pageIndicatorLibrary:generateDebugSources, :pageIndicatorLibrary:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :facebook:generateDebugSources, :facebook:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :pullToRefreshLibrary:generateDebugSources, :pullToRefreshLibrary:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:qpals:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:qpals:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:qpals:checkDebugManifest
:facebook:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileLint
:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:facebook:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:checkReleaseManifest
:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript
:facebook:generateReleaseResValues
:facebook:generateReleaseResources
:facebook:packageReleaseResources
:facebook:compileReleaseAidl
:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:facebook:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets
:facebook:processReleaseManifest
:facebook:processReleaseResources
:facebook:generateReleaseSources
:facebook:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:facebook:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:facebook:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:facebook:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:facebook:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:facebook:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:facebook:bundleRelease
:pageIndicatorLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:compileLint
:pageIndicatorLibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:pageIndicatorLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
:pageIndicatorLibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies
:pageIndicatorLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript
:pageIndicatorLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
:pageIndicatorLibrary:generateReleaseResources
:pageIndicatorLibrary:packageReleaseResources
:pageIndicatorLibrary:compileReleaseAidl
:pageIndicatorLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:pageIndicatorLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:mergeReleaseAssets
:pageIndicatorLibrary:processReleaseManifest
:pageIndicatorLibrary:processReleaseResources
:pageIndicatorLibrary:generateReleaseSources
:pageIndicatorLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:pageIndicatorLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:pageIndicatorLibrary:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:pageIndicatorLibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:pageIndicatorLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:pageIndicatorLibrary:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:pageIndicatorLibrary:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:pageIndicatorLibrary:bundleRelease
:pullToRefreshLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:compileLint
:pullToRefreshLibrary:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:pullToRefreshLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
:pullToRefreshLibrary:prepareReleaseDependencies
:pullToRefreshLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript
:pullToRefreshLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
:pullToRefreshLibrary:generateReleaseResources
:pullToRefreshLibrary:packageReleaseResources
:pullToRefreshLibrary:compileReleaseAidl
:pullToRefreshLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:pullToRefreshLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:mergeReleaseAssets
:pullToRefreshLibrary:processReleaseManifest
:pullToRefreshLibrary:processReleaseResources
:pullToRefreshLibrary:generateReleaseSources
:pullToRefreshLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\pullToRefreshLibrary\src\main\java\com\handmark\pulltorefresh\library\PullToRefreshWebView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:pullToRefreshLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:pullToRefreshLibrary:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:pullToRefreshLibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:pullToRefreshLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:pullToRefreshLibrary:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:pullToRefreshLibrary:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:pullToRefreshLibrary:bundleRelease
:qpals:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:qpals:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library
:qpals:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library
:qpals:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library
:qpals:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library
:qpals:prepareQpalsFacebookUnspecifiedLibrary
:qpals:prepareQpalsPageIndicatorLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary
:qpals:prepareQpalsPullToRefreshLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary
:qpals:prepareDebugDependencies
:qpals:compileDebugAidl
:qpals:compileDebugRenderscript
:qpals:generateDebugBuildConfig
:qpals:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:qpals:mergeDebugAssets
:qpals:generateDebugResValues
:qpals:generateDebugResources
:qpals:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 2091427456): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\cross.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 136203471): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\back.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 365090968): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\menu.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 117274438): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2091427456): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\settings_arrow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2043780643): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\settings_arrow_bottom.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1183576705): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\settings_arrow_bottom.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 849880358): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1147920227): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT err(Facade for 1147920227): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 849880358): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\settings_arrow_bottom.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1183576705): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2043780643): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\settings_arrow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2091427456): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\back.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 117274438): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\arrow_up.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 365090968): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 136203471): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\chat_left_arrow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 365090968): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\twitter.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 117274438): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\badge_new.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2091427456): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\secondary_email_hover.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2043780643): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\filter_active.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1183576705): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\logo_qpals.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 849880358): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\camera_roll.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1147920227): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\camera_frame.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\settings_arrow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1147920227): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\camera_roll.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 849880358): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\qwall_comment_count.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1183576705): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\edit.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2091427456): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-ldpi-v4\close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 117274438): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\settings_arrow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 365090968): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\pullToRefreshLibrary\unspecified\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 136203471): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\menu.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 365090968): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\facebook.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 117274438): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\menu.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 2091427456): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\search_icon_group.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 849880358): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\menu.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1147920227): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 365090968): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 136203471): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\settings_arrow_bottom.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\arrow_down.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\menu.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-ldpi-v4\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 722766407): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\icon_votedpals_cross.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 573677099): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\cameragroup.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 573677099): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\pinterest.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 573677099): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\camera_roll.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 573677099): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\cameraflip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 573677099): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\defaultimage_q.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 573677099): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\flashon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1155686400): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\search_icon_qwall.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1155686400): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\defaultimage_group.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1155686400): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\pullToRefreshLibrary\unspecified\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1155686400): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\back.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 426689225): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\search_icon_findpals.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 426689225): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\back.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1520498888): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\flashoff.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1520498888): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\filter.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1520498888): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1520498888): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\camera_roll.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1520498888): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\retake_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\qpals.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable\close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\new_icon_qwall.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\back.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\pullToRefreshLibrary\unspecified\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 60908718): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1046266409): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\chat_right_arrow.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1046266409): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\icon_cross.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1046266409): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\defaultimage_profile.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 1046266409): E:\Works\Android Studio Projects\Qpals\qpals\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\Qpals\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
Error:Execution failed for task ':qpals:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

The icons and images are just warnings. I am not able to understand what is the error that is causing the build failure.
I have tried cleaning and rebuilding several times.

Comment: before running (Build > Rebuild Project)

Comment: @sasikumar I have tried it, every time the same error is coming

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still have this problem, but try this:

```
 aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

in your gradle file