# Android error crunching failed when android studio start ?

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details.

when I run my project android studio give error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception)

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows I had a "BUILD FAILED Failed to crunch file [path]" error and solved it by closing the Android Studio project, copying the entire project folder into a location with a shorter directory path, such as my C: folder and then opening the project in the new location. Hope it helps**

Answer (score 0):

Please add entry in build.gradle for cruncher

```
android { 
    ....
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    ....
}
```