# App debug issue

Tags: android, debugging, release

When i debug my app it will show an error like 
    BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 41.485 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk450Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesContextmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils044Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComToptocheSearchablespinnerSearchablespinnerlibrary131Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgSolovyevAndroidViewsLinearLayoutManager05Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: D:\OnGoiningProjrct\drzone\app\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.975 secs

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception

Comment: not that class path is already added with updated version

Comment: Check if google-services.json is inside your app folder.

Comment: current app google-services.json is already there

Answer (score 0):

Add your `google-services.json` file inside /app folder and try again. This file is necessary when using the Google Play Services SDK.

Comment: link already referred its says about class path class path is already added with updated version

Comment: Let me do some research, then I will tell you the exact answer.

Comment: Got it, its images issue deleted last added image then problem solved