# Error: failed to open file. Android Studio 3

Tags: java, android

how are you?
I just download the Android Studio 3 for Windows 10 64bits.
I started a new proyect but when it does the automatically build give me some errors. 
I tried:
 Uninstalling and installing again de Android S3.
 Changing the "region settings" of windows to "USA".
 Antivirus diseable.

I dont know what else to do, i cant start any proyect because always is the same errors.

This is on Message Gradle Build:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\Cam\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml

Error:error: failed to open file: Datos no válidos. (13).

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'mergeDebugResources' property 'incrementalFolder' during up-to-date check.
```

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file **'C:\Users\Cam\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml'.**

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the project by doing:
       Build -> Rebuild

Also try different versions of gradle.
See [Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Rebuild and Clean Project