# Build gradle fails even in new apps

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, chocolatey

I keep getting the same error

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' no servers to serve "

This happened after I installed glade via choco.

I deleted every folder of android studio(.gradle, sdk, projects, etc) and deleted choco in the %programdata% folder, I reinstalled android studio and keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gradle needs to be updated so that the folder is not private. Sometimes that error is "spat" when your folder with the project, for some reason, becomes unaccessible and you should redirect it via a chmod command in the terminal. That is what I did running Android Studio on Linux when I got the same error you are having.
Typed: 
'sudo chmod 777 -R ~/Desktop/folder_project'

Where folder_project is the folder that I used when I put with root my android sdk.

A similar problem with yours, was faced by the person asking this Q: [Android Studio - mergeDebugResources exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121033/android-studio-mergedebugresources-exception)